# #!/bin/bash --login vs #!/bin/bash

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, jenkins

I read some following script when looking for script to run Appium with Jenkins

```
#!/bin/bash --login

killall -9 "iPhone Simulator" &> /dev/null
killall -9 node &> /dev/null
killall -9 instruments &> /dev/null
...
```

I don't understand why the first line of the script needs to pass a `--login` option here. I have read the man page but still have some confusions.
What I get from the man page is that passing `--login` to make the script be called as `login shell` instead of `interactive` shell. `interactive` shell is the shell that users can interact with the shell, like input something with keyboard. But what is `login shell`? I checked the man page that it said `login shell` would load `~/.bash_profile`, but if open the terminal through Mac OSX's Terminal.app, it also loads the `~/.bash_profile` and I am able to interactive with the shell,right? So, the shell I open is both `login shell` and `interactive shell`?

Comment: Yes, a shell can be both a "login" and "interactive" shell. And no, the fact that `.bash_profile` was read doesn't necessarily mean that. Most people do not understand the way the shell init stuff works and so have links from one set of init files to the other so that no matter what type of shell it is all the things are loaded (this is the default config on many distributions even).

Comment: I would raise a support issue with the supplier.  I can't see a good reason for doing this with this script.  Anything required should be exported or specifically set.  Relying on the user's startup files in a 3rd party product is asking for trouble, and is an unnecessary overhead.  My suspicion is that this is unintentional.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that a login shell executes your profile when it starts. From the man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it  first  reads  and
>       executes  commands  from  the  file  /etc/profile,  if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>          ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists  and  is  readable.
>          The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

Comment: so `login shell` is just shell that load ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile first, then execute your script, right?

Comment: yes. The script probably uses that option so that it will get settings for things like `PATH` that you set in your profile.